# iOS - Async NSURLConnection inside NSOperation

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, nsoperation

I know this question was asked many times on SO, but I didn't manage to make it work in my project...

So, I want to subclass `NSOperation` and make it download a file using `NSURLConnection`. What is the right way to do it? 
here is my code which doesn't work:
First, I'm adding all my operations in a loop:

```
DownloadFileOperation *operation;
NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
operation = [[DownloadFileOperation alloc] init];
operation.urlString = pdfUrlString;
[queue addOperation:operation];
operation = nil; }
```

And here is my subclass:

```
@interface DownloadHandbookOperation : NSOperation <NSURLConnectionDelegate>
{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *urlString;

@end


@implementation DownloadHandbookOperation
{
    NSString *filePath;
    NSFileHandle *file;
    NSURLConnection * connection;
}

- (void)start
{
    if (![NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(start) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }

    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[self.urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *req = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [req addValue:@"Basic ***=" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    NSString *filename = [[conn.originalRequest.URL absoluteString] lastPathComponent];
    filename = [filename stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil];

    file = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForUpdatingAtPath:filePath] ;
    if (file)
    {
        [file seekToEndOfFile];
    }
    else
        [self finish];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    if (file) {
        [file seekToEndOfFile];
    }
    [file writeData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)conn
{
    [file closeFile];
    [self finish];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    connection = nil;

    [self finish];
}

- (void)cancel
{
    [super cancel];
    [connection cancel];
}


- (void)finish
{
    NSLog(@"operationfinished.");
}


@end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think `NSURLConnection` has to be called from the main thread, it doesn't do anything if called from a background thread... Also even though it's called from the main thread it still actually does the network stuff in the background, and then calls your delegate functions from the main thread again...

Comment: Right, so how can I make my NSOperation be executed on main thread then?

Comment: Try `[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation]`...

Comment: It worked, but now I can't control my queue and cancel/track operations?

Comment: Yes, it wasn't really designed for being used in an operation queue... I'm not sure how you can put a NSURLConnection in a NSOperation, it should really be used on it's own, so you store the NSURLConnection objects and if you want to stop one of them call [connection cancel]...

Comment: Please see my answer.. `NSURLConnection` is concurrent as it comes with it's own background threading.  To use it in an NSOperation you need to create a Concurrent `NSOperation`.  It's what the concurrent part of `NSOperation` was invented for.  Also see the `LinkedImageFetcher` sample code and `QRunLoopOperation`.  Also search for `QA1712` in the documentation. You need a concurrent operation, I've recently done this myself.

Comment: Also you already had some code in `-start` to get the connection running on the main thread not sure why that wasn't working for you?

Comment: The problem is that NSOperation is run in background, when I start my NSURLConnection, it tries to create one more background thread, kind of background in background. None of NSURLConnection delegate methods are being called

Comment: Yes.  NSURLConnection runs on a background thread, another way to describe this is to say that NSURLConnection "is concurrent".  How do you stop NSOperation running "background in background"?  You tell it that your operation is already concurrent by returning `isConcurrent = YES`.  This tells NSOperation not to create a separate background thread for this operation.  Your operation will handle this. Once you take control you also have to say when you are finished through `isFinished` and `isExecuting`.  I'll try to dig out a good example and add it to my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to properly configure your operation to execute as a "concurrent operation"

[Concurrency Programming Guide: Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8)

You need to return `isConcurrent = YES` and properly manage the other state flags, `isExecuting` and `isFinished` in a KVO compliant manner.

---

To illustrate the general idea here is a post from the engineers at Pulse that describes their solution with some easy to follow demo code you can download and review.

[Pulse Engineering Blog: Concurrent Downloads using NSOperationQueues](http://web.archive.org/web/20110812034830/http://eng.alphonsolabs.com/concurrent-downloads-using-nsoperationqueues/) **

This code also handles the requirement that NSURLConnection is started on a thread with an active runloop by ensuring that it starts it on the main thread.

(** link is now to archive.org, I think pulse was acquired and have taken their old site down)

Comment: Good that GitHub is still alive :) and you can find source code for second link here: https://github.com/alphonsolabs/Operations-Demo/blob/master/OperationsDemo/DownloadUrlOperation.m